# javascript private members not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get private properties to work in javascript.

```
        var obj = function() {
            var a = 0;
            this.run = function() {
                var q = a;
                a += 1;
                return q; 
            };
        };
        alert(obj.run());
        alert(obj.run());
```

I have a private variable `a` and a public function `run`, however when I call it, it throws an error saying obj.run is not a function. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create instance of your `obj`

```
var o = new obj();

console.log(o.run());
console.log(o.run());
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/norubu/1/edit?js,console),

or you can use [module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript), like so

```
var obj = (function() {
  var a = 0;

  return {
    run: function () {
      var q = a;
      a += 1;
      return q; 
    }
  };
})();

console.log(obj.run());
console.log(obj.run());
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/norubu/2/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

> the value of this is determined by how a function is called. (Context)

your obj is a function type. It has not been called, not been invoked, or no instance of it has been created yet. Thats y 'this' here refers to window object, not function obj type. Context is 'window' here

```
this.run = function () {
      //code
}

// here the context is window, hence attaches run property to window 
// object making run method accessible in global scope.
```

When you do

```
obj.run() 
// remember 'this' to be window , this statement will not work, 
// because obj doesn't have run property.
```

When you create instance of obj like

```
var o = new obj(); // context of 'this' is set to function now
```

so, if you call o.run() // it will work.

[this in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)